# My php code is not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql

So, i was working on my website. And after 10 minutes I was ready. I tried it. I have 4 column in my database. `id`, `times`, `left_over` and `bruh`. When I tried it Everything was getting inserted but not `bruh`, I don't know what I've did wrong. Here is my script:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testang");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$channelid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['channelid']);
$subs = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['subs']);
$points = $subs*20;
$lell = $userRow['userid'];
$lel = $userRow['userpoints'];
$pointsreal = $lel - $points;
if ($points > $lel) {
header("Refresh:0; url=NO.php");
}
$bew = "INSERT INTO yt (times, left_over, bruh)
VALUES ('0', '$subs', '$channelid')";
if ($link->query($bew) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $bew . "<br>" . $link->error;
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

And I don't get any messages that there's gone something wrong. Everything is getting inserted but `bruh` not. Does some one know why?

This is my form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">Youtube channel ID</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="channelid">
    </p><br><br>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">What is your email?</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="subs" id="subs">
    </p><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Most likely your variable `$channelid` is null.

Comment: Show us your HTML form. Also, you should consider using prepared statements.

Comment: But I have this: ` <label for="firstName">Youtube channel ID</label><br><input type="text" name="id" id="channelid">`

Comment: It should be `name="channelid"`

Comment: I've added my form

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas Thank you!

Comment: It works now :D

Comment: Interesting how coders still do not parameterize SQL queries, an industry best practice especially working on the web. See one of the highest upvoted [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

Now that I know from comments what's wrong, let me clarify a bit what's wrong in here. In your field:

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="channelid">
```

You have ID: `channelid` and name: `id`. To be able to get `$_POST['channelid']`, you need to set attribute `name` with the same string as in your `$_POST` index. Therefore:

```
<input type="text" name="channelid" id="channelid">
```

Comment: @Aaron  [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) ... that's how we roll here.